# Change state of ToggleButton when clicked, and show in another list

Tags: android, listview, togglebutton

please help me.

i have a listview with ToggleButton.

i just need help on how i can toggle or select listview item.

please see image below.

[image]

in the image at the top, i have heart ToggleButton.

when i click the heart it will turn to red then vise versa.

but i dont know how to do that.

also after i click heart i want to display those item with heart in my favorites.

here is my adapter..

```
package com.magicstarme.virtualsongbook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Joe on 6/29/2016.
 */
public class FragmentOne_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> oneslArrayList;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public FragmentOne_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> slresults) {
        oneslArrayList = slresults;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return oneslArrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return oneslArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one_slview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.txtArtist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
            holder.txtVolume = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.volume);
            holder.txtNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);



            holder.btnFavourite = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
            holder.btnFavourite.setChecked(true);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtArtist.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getArtist());
        holder.txtVolume.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getVolume());
        holder.txtNumber.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getNumber());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtArtist;
        TextView txtVolume;
        TextView txtNumber;
        ImageButton buttonHeart;
        ToggleButton btnFavourite;
    }
}
```

here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="3
        ">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/artist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/volume"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout3">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/mic"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:src="@drawable/mic"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:background="#ffffff" />



            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
                style="@style/toggleButton"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                android:background="@drawable/favourite_toggle_bg"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#cccccc">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is my fragment.

```
package com.magicstarme.virtualsongbook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FragmentOne#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentOne.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentOne newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);

        TabHost host = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        host.setup();

        //Tab 1
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("SONG LIST");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("SONG LIST");
        host.addTab(spec);

            ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> slResults = GetSearchResults();
        final ListView sllv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slListView);
        sllv.setAdapter(new FragmentOne_Adapter(getActivity(), slResults));


        //Tab 2
        spec = host.newTabSpec("NEW SONGS");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec.setIndicator("NEW SONGS");
        host.addTab(spec);

        //Tab 3
        spec = host.newTabSpec("FAVORITES");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        spec.setIndicator("FAVORITES");
        host.addTab(spec);

        return rootView;
    }

    //SONG LIST
    private ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> results = new ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults>();

        FragmentOne_slResults slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("1");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 1 Song Title 1 Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 1");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 1");
        slr.setNumber("1");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("2");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("2");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("3");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("3");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("4");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("4");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("5");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("5");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("6");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("6");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("7");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2 Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 23 tle 2 Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("7");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("8");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("8");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("9");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("9");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("10");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("10");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("11");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("11");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("12");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("12");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("13");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("13");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("14");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("14");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("15");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("15");
        results.add(slr);


        return results;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

how can i do that? please help me.

Comment: Jaxian, don't add irrelevant tags. Your reasons to add it are not valid

Comment: can someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle the heart, you can set an `OnCheckedChangeListener` on the toggle button as follows:

```
btnFavourite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled, change the heart color to red
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled, change to the default heart
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried this but when i click one heart, other heart will toggle too.

Comment: below holder.btnFavourite = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

Answer (score 0):

You don't handle the list items click toggle properly without use of POJO classes.

Means you need to handle these toggle by POJO classes to create setter and getter and change bool value inside the class variables setter and then it gives correct toggle value when you scroll or reload list again means it give correct response with the help of these.

So use a POJO class with list-view items.

```
(A) In Adapter
```

extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private ArrayList<ChildListResponse> itemsData;

viewHolder.checkParentView.setTag(itemsData.get(position));
    viewHolder.checkParentView.setOnClickListener(checkedListener);

private View.OnClickListener checkedListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ChildListResponse childListResponse = (ChildListResponse) v.getTag();
        if (childListResponse.isSelected())
            childListResponse.setSelected(false);
        else
            childListResponse.setSelected(true);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Comment: can you help me to construct my code? im new to android. please. thanks.

Comment: (A) In Adapter 

 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ChildListResponse> itemsData;



/*  In Bind View Holder */

  viewHolder.checkParentView.setTag(itemsData.get(position));
        viewHolder.checkParentView.setOnClickListener(checkedListener);

Comment: /* A clicklistener of a toogle image */

private View.OnClickListener checkedListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ChildListResponse childListResponse = (ChildListResponse) v.getTag();
            if (childListResponse.isSelected())
                childListResponse.setSelected(false);
            else
                childListResponse.setSelected(true);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

Comment: (B) 

/* A POJO Class */

public class ChildListResponse {

private boolean isSelected;

  public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

Comment: one more. can you edit your answer and post this comment? because it is not clear. thanks..